# DLL Runtime Loading in C#

Tags: c#, dll, unmanaged

I have a DLL `Foo.dll` that I want to load into the process space. This DLL is native and unmanaged. I also have a static class `NativeMethods` which contains function delegates for `LoadLibrary`, `GetProcAddress` and `FreeLibrary` that are called from `Kernel32.dll`. These work fine as I can get a pointer when trying to load `Kernel32.dll`.

My problem lies in the fact that within my bin folder I have setup a directory called `modules` which will contain all my unmanaged Dll's. When I try to load `Foo` from this directory, the `LoadLibrary` function returns a zero pointer, however when I try and load it from the bin directory I get a pointer that points to a memory address.

My DLL's are Loaded as follows:

```
IntPtr dll = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\modules\\Foo.dll"); 
//dll = 0

IntPtr dll = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Foo.dll");
//dll = address
```

Any help with this matter would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is the value of `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`? May be there's any other unmanaged library from your `Foo.dll` depends, which resides in your `bin` directory.

Comment: What if you use the Add/SetDllDirectory to the modules path? and load it like you did normal?

Comment: @Dennis I Have checked that there are no missing unmanaged DLL's using depends.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Where would I find the Add/SetDllDirectory methods?

Comment: Using Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() is asking for trouble.  You just don't have much control over that.  Always start from the directory where your EXE is located, Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location

Comment: Kernel32.dll http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203(v=vs.85).aspx. Good notice Hans +1

Comment: Thank You @HansPassant for the tip about using the assembly load point, the dll seems to be loading fine now, even using the Directory.CurrentDirectory() method. Not quite sure what changed but it seems to be working.